# Is there such a thing as Jupyter Notebooks just for markdown?

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I started making notes on a software process using the code and markdown cells in a jupyter notebook and realised that while I didn't actually use the code cells and was just using it as a notebook, having the live rendering of Markdown cells in Google Collaboratory and the natural segmentation of sections that come with notebooks was extremely convenient to making styled notes.

So what I'm wondering is if I can just have the markdown cells in a notebook without worrying about environments, cell magic, etc.